# Swift iOS - Detect Touch Drag Enter UIView from outside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, events, drag

How do I get an event for a Touch, anywhere on the screen, that is draged and enters a specific UIView?

How can I do it, in a simple way, in Swift for iOS?

An example of what I want to achieve is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Override method of controller

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }
```

than check if any touch is inside of your views rect using function `CGRectContainsPoint`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button on the top of yourView and add touchDrag Inside control to it.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: yourView.bounds)
button.addTarget(target: self, action:#selector(self.yourmethodName), forControlEvents: .TouchDragInside)
```

[Apple Documentation Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents) :

> TouchDragInside 
>    An event where a finger is dragged inside the bounds
>    of the control.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> TouchDragOutside An event where a
>   finger is dragged just outside the bounds of the control.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.